# playing wav files on the iso disc

Tags: unity

Can I play audio files off of windows7 while I am trying out Ubuntu with just the iso disk without installing it.  Is it possible to access windows files while in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I play audio files off of windows7 while I am trying out Ubuntu with just the iso disk without installing it.

Yes, you can. There is probably not audio software installed during the live dvd session so you need to load it in to memory with Ubuntu Software Center. You can also use the command line tool called "aplay" to play sounds (it supports a multitude of formats).

> Is it possible to access windows files while in Ubuntu?

Yes. Ubuntu will mount them by itself during boot unless you tell it not to.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mount your windows partition in ubuntu and access the files from there. Be careful not to delete anything important from the windows partition while you are browsing it though.

Firstly, you could try opening the nautilus file browser and see if your windows disk is listed in the left hand pane. If you see a disk icon that looks like it might be your windows disk, give it a click and browse the files to see.

If that doesn't work, you can mount it from the command line. So open a terminal, and use fdisk to find your partition:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

    Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
    /dev/sdb1               1   976773167   46905263    ee  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

We want the partition which has *NTFS* listed under System. In this example, it's /dev/sdb1, so lets try to mount it. **Don't just use sdb1 in the following command though; make sure you use the /dev/sdXX name from your own fdisk -l output**.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/win
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/win
```

You should be able to browse the files in the folder /mnt/win. Hopefully that should help.